# long running query PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I need some help with PostgreSQL.  I have a table with 32 Columns, and 2 million plus rows.  I have two foreign keys and one index.  When I query the table it takes 8+ seconds to return 60,000+ rows.  I have tried everything that I have found on the web including tips on Stack Overflow and can get no improvement on the query.  BTW, the query is a simple select of half of the columns with no group by or order by statement.  I ran the EXPLAIN ANALYZE command and the results are below.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?  Thank you very much in advance.

```
"Seq Scan on mydatatable a  (cost=0.00..336085.02 rows=40944 width=156) (actual time=1244.135..7139.903 rows=60576 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((customer_id = 123) AND (vip_period_id = 555))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 2070509"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..5.05 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.065..0.068 rows=1 loops=60576)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on countries b  (cost=0.00..5.05 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=1 loops=60576)"
"                Filter: ((a.endcustomercountry)::text = (iso3)::text)"
"                Rows Removed by Filter: 231"
"Total runtime: 7326.915 ms"
```

Sorry, I forgot to add the query:

```
select a.id, a.color, a.grade, round((a.allocationpercentage)::numeric, 2) AS percent, 
    a.product, a.customer, a.actualshipmentdate, 
    round((a.booknet)::numeric, 2) AS allocated, 
    round((a.cost)::numeric, 2) AS cost, 
    round((a.rebate)::numeric, 2) AS rebate, 
    COALESCE(round((a.forecast)::numeric, 2), 0.00) AS forecast, 
    round((a.estimatedforecast)::numeric, 2) AS estforecast, 
    c.countryname, a.transactiondate, a.sellerpo, a.sopo, a.quantity 
    from mydatatable as a left outer join countries as c on a.endcustomercountry = c.iso3
    where a.customer_id = 123 AND a.vip_period_id = 555;

CREATE TABLE mydatatable
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  sopo integer,
  transactiondate date,
  partner character varying(110),
  color character varying(100),
  grade character varying(100),
  allocationpercentage double precision,
  technologytier character varying(250),
  product character varying(100),
  promotionname character varying(100),
  dealiddartid integer,
  dartdescriptor character varying(250),
  quantity integer,
  routetomarket character varying(100),
  endcustomername character varying(200),
  endcustomerparentname character varying(200),
  endcustomercountry character varying(20),
  shipmentflag character varying(20),
  actualshipmentdate date,
  oipsipflag character varying(250),
  reasondescription character varying(200),
  totalbooknet double precision,
  booknet double precision,
  rebate double precision,
  customer_id integer,
  entry_datetime timestamp without time zone,
  forecast double precision,
  sellerpo character varying(111),
  vip_period_id integer DEFAULT 1,
  pollersessionid integer,
  estimatedcost double precision DEFAULT 0,
  estimatedforecast double precision DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT mydatatable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT mydatatable_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES customer (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT mydatatable_vip_period_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (vip_period_id)
      REFERENCES vipperiod (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE mydatatable
  OWNER TO myowner;

CREATE INDEX idx_mydatatable
  ON mydatatable
  USING btree
  (customer_id, vip_period_id);
```

```
{
"Hash Left Join  (cost=11101.47..81592.05 rows=39533 width=164) (actual time=73.286..434.876 rows=60576 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((a.endcustomercountry)::text = (c.iso3)::text)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mydatatable a  (cost=11093.98..79266.39 rows=39299 width=157) (actual time=73.174..104.951 rows=60576 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((customer_id = 123) AND (vip_period_id = 555))"
"        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=11093.98..11093.98 rows=39299 width=0) (actual time=72.700..72.700 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_cid_mydatatable  (cost=0.00..4038.51 rows=218411 width=0) (actual time=41.377..41.377 rows=221793 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (customer_id = 123)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_vip_mydatatable  (cost=0.00..7035.57 rows=380685 width=0) (actual time=28.829..28.829 rows=372877 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (vip_period_id = 555)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=4.44..4.44 rows=244 width=15) (actual time=0.075..0.075 rows=235 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on countries c  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=244 width=15) (actual time=0.011..0.037 rows=244 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 436.599 ms"
}
```

Comment: Please re-format the query(s) in your question because it is almost unreadable so we can help you. I can't even find the original SQL Quey.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the query:

Comment: Show us the database schema.  That is, show us the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements you used to set up your database.

Comment: If you remove the subquery for country match ((select b.countryname from countries as b where a.endcustomercountry=b.iso3 limit 1) as country) does query time decrease?

Comment: I have tried removing the subquery and it only improves it by 500 MS.  I also tried using a join and I get the same time 8+ seconds.  I also tried re-creating the table with all of the integers first and text values at the end and this did nothing.  I increased the working memory and saw no improvement.

Comment: ok. As long as I can see you have one coumpound index with the two fields. Try make two indexes one per each field.

Comment: Just dropped the one Index on the two fields and added the two per your suggestion and get the same results: 8+ seconds.  BTW, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you update the query and the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results?

Comment: Just added it to the end of the post.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is what the EXPLAIN ANALYZE says but when I execute the query it still takes 8+ seconds to return results.  When I look at the computer management console I see no appreciable impact on the cpu or memory.  I am at a loss.

Comment: You say you tried "everything". What have you tried, specifically? Have you adjusted cost parameters? Have you, for testing, played with the `enable_` planner params to see if there's actually a faster plan possible?